# How to fix the position of div's in responsive UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have to display the content in a grid. All items are div's with random height, and I need to have control over how they are displayed. It is a responsive UI with 4-cols, 3-cols and 1-cols. Assume that X's are available in javascript array and G are the google ad's.

Is there any classes that I can use in foundation to achieve this. Or do I need to dynamically generate the grid based on the resolution.

4*4

```
X  2  3  X
5  G  7  X
9  X  11 12
```

3*3

```
X 2 X
4 G X
7 X 9
```

Comment: If they are all the same width, it should be easy with CSS, this helped me http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html

Comment: It has to fallback to 3-cols with mentioned format. If I were to layout 4 divs using inline, while viewing in smaller device the first column in 3*3 layout would be X 2 3 instead of X 2 X

Comment: Also adding to that, Google Ad and placing item below it is a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CSS grid layout: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```
.grid-container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "item-1 item-2 item-3 item-4"
    "item-5 item-6 item-7 item-8"
    "item-9 item-10 item-11 item-12";
}

.item-1 {grid-area:item-1} /* For each item inside grid */
```

And, when you want to change grid appearance (eg. in `@media` query), just overwrite the `.grid-container`'s style.

JSFiddle with working example: https://jsfiddle.net/qd4np55L/